# getting counter flow errored : when changing from validating Notary to Non Validating Notary

Tags: corda

I have been working with a validating notary all this time . For analysis I made the Notary as non validating . When I started sending requests I am getting

> counter-flow errored

On seeing the Notary logs I am getting TypecastException stating that signedTransaction cannot be cast to CoreTransaction. Has anyone ecountered a similar situation . Please let me know . FYI : I am using the "**FinalityFlow**" which takes the signedTransaction as a parameter. (edited)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I had not rebuilt my nodes when I made the validating notary as non validating it threw the error. Once I rebuilt the nodes it worked fine. But not sure whether is it possible to make a validating notary into non-validating by just configuring in the node.conf file.

Answer (score 2):

For anyone else having this problem, it is not possible to switch a validating notary to non-validating and vice versa.

When registering a notary on the network, its identity is added to the network parameters along with a flag for whether it's validating or not, and that can't be changed.
Clients then use this flag to know whether to send a `SignedTransaction` (full) or a `FilteredTransaction` to a specific notary.